# Block cipher's output in case of uniformly drawn input

Tags: encryption, block-cipher

Consider a **block cipher** $E_k$ where $k$ is an arbitrary key. $E_k$ takes input messages from $\{0,1\}^n$ and outputs a ciphertext $c\in\{0,1\}^n$. Let $m$ be an input message which is **uniformly drawn from $\{0,1\}^n$** and let $c = E_k(m)$.

My question is simple - is $c$ also uniformly distributed in $\{0,1\}^n$?

Note: I know that $c$ has to be indistinguishable from a uniform distribution, but I ask if it is actually uniformly distributed. I'd appreciate a proof (or proof sketch) in case it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **yes**.
While I can't provide a rigorous proof (because I don't know for now how to make one for such distributions), I can give an intuitive argument, which you can formalize I hope.

The main reason is simple: $E_k$ is a permutation for all choices of $k$.
This means that essentially all the encryption function does is "re-label" the given input message, there are no collisions (which would change the distribution) and input- and output space are equal in size so, every value in the input space is mapped to precisely one value in the output space and vice-versa.

So if you have probability $1/2^n$ of drawing $m$ you have probability of $1/2^n$ of ending up with $E_k(m)=c$ and so $c$ is distributed uniformly at random.

Comment: I guess formally one could argue using a contrapositive and show that a non-uniform distribution would follow from a non-uniform distribution among the ciphertexts.

Comment: Thanks! I'm quite new to the terminology too, but is cipher block always a PRP (pseudo-random permutation)?

Comment: @noamgot actually you don't need to assume that you have _pseudorandom_ permutation because you don't need this property anywhere in the proof. You just need that it's a permutation and that follows from the functional correctness and from the equal, finite size of message and ciphertext space.